# drop data base from mysql in centos(Linux)

Tags: mysql, linux, database, diskspace, centos5

i have deleted  one of my database from mysql server because that was useless and taking too much space from the hard disk and after deleting it my disk space is still the same it doesn't effect my disk space .Please suggest me how can i competently remove or drop my database i used drop command for dropping it.

DROP DATABASE;

Comment: From [this Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/232525/df-in-linux-not-showing-correct-free-space-after-file-removal) question, one possibility is that MySQL is still holding a file handle on the database, for some reason.  If so, then the space taken up would still be counted by Linux.

Answer (score 0):

For drop db from mysql on centos 7 should do under command :

```
Mysql -u root -p
Drop yourDBName;
```